# Get TransactionStatus from Ethers Contract call

Tags: ethers.js, gnosis-safe

I'm building a Gnosis Safe app, and I'd like my react UI to respond to changes in the [TransactionStatus](https://github.com/safe-global/safe-react-gateway-sdk/blob/main/src/types/transactions.ts#L32) of a transaction submitted via an `ethers.js` contract function call. I see a way to get the `Transaction` and thus the status from the transaction hash using `sdk.txs.getBySafeTxHash`, but I do not see a way to get the hash from a contract call.

In particular, it would be nice to know when a user dismisses the transaction confirmation modal without submitting a signed transaction to the network, or when they reject the transaction in the wallet interface.

Answer (score 1):

Proposed transactions are not created on-chain; it's part of the Safe internal infrastructure. Therefore, you wouldn't be able to query the state of a transaction using a web3 library like ethers until the transaction has been executed.

I'm not familiar enough with the Safe SDK to know whether the UI actions are possible, but you can always get the status of a transaction using the [Safe Transaction Service](https://safe-transaction-mainnet.safe.global/)'s `v1/multisig-transactions/{hash}/` endpoint.